# My WordPress website loads index.php not the website

Tags: php, wordpress, cpanel

I migrated my website to a new server however when you go to the site it loads index.php not the WordPress site.

[image]

File Structure 
[image]

I copied the public_html folder and database from my old server. I don't know where to go from here.

Comment: posting the directory structure will help

Comment: have checked URL rewrite is enabled or not?

Comment: if not may be you should config htaccess rewrite url

Comment: @Rajnish Done! Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: PHP does not get executed, that’s why you get to see the actual code of the index.php. Figure out why that is the case - check the hoster’s documentation for whether you have to enable it first or something like that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP code is not being executed, instead code shows on the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-instead-code-shows-on-the-page)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your account php version. You can do that by logging into your cPanel account, the search for PHP or MultiPHP. See what default version is currently configured and try switching that to a different version. Test your website again and see if it works or not. If you get the same error, then you should contact your hosting provider since they're pretty much the only ones who can actually help